# stop twitter embed having such a large bottom margin?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there a way to get the twitter embed code for tweets to not have such a massive margin on the bottom of them?

Using the generic embed code twitter gives you:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>@<a href="https://twitter.com/gamingonlinux">gamingonlinux</a> the Mac version is taking us longer than we anticipated, so the Linux version has been shifted, too. We'll keep you posted!</p>— Strike Suit Zero (@StrikeSuitZero) <a href="https://twitter.com/StrikeSuitZero/status/326626905392545792">April 23, 2013</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Link: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/strike-suit-zero-space-combat-game-delayed-for-linux.1942

Comment: There is a `<br>` tag before and after `<script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

There's also a problem with:

```
<div id='AYAH'></div><script src='https://ws.areyouahuman.com/ws/script/175542a83683bff431e8fce2f2e1336470c11a63/51766b1e3587f' type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'></script>
```

Which adds an iframe with a height of 200px but no content:

```
<iframe id="AYAH_iframe1366715281731" src="https://ws.areyouahuman.com//ws/chooseGame/1/1/51766b8f6f114/11-7" width="400" height="200" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Indeed nothing to do with my actual posted issue though, this has been fixed anyway.